# Creating a starting player with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I got a problem right now. I need to create a starting player menu with the options on how many players and giving those players a color. Also whenever a player has a color, the color will get deleted from a list.

Can any1 help me :(

Comment: Questions made up of "how do I solve this problem without thinking" don't really go down well on Stack Overflow.   This stuff is pretty much covered in any introduction to Pygame (e.g. https://nebelprog.wordpress.com/2013/08/14/create-a-simple-game-menu-with-pygame-pt-1-writing-the-menu-options-to-the-screen/).

  Until you've tried something, failed and explained where you are having a specific problem it'll be hard to find help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can treat menu almost as `separated game` - with own `mainloop`, own functions and classes - but in the same file with rest of code.

And use `pygame.init()`, `pygame.display.set_mode()` only once - when you `init game`.

[image]

Latter you can find better solution (but more complicated) with only one `mainloop` - Finite-State Machine "FSM"